# Solspace composer template if field_type = file

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, file-uploads, fieldtype, composer-template

I want to change the output of the standard file upload field with something similar to "[Whipping File Inputs Into Shape with Bootstrap 3](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/)". I am using the following conditional in my Solspace Freeform Pro composer template in an attempt to change the output for file upload field types:

```
{composer:fields}
{if composer:field_output}
                    {if composer:field_type == 'nonfield_captcha'}
                        {if freeform:captcha}
                                {freeform:captcha}<br />
                                <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" style="width:140px;" />
                        {/if}

                     {if:elseif composer:field_type == 'file'}

                          <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                              Browse {composer:field_output}
                          </span>

                    {if:else}

                        {composer:field_output}

                    {/if}
                {/if}
{/composer:fields}
```

The if:elseif field type "file" statement doesn't seem to work in the template and has no effect in the output when the form is rendered:

```
{if:elseif composer:field_type == "file"}
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
      Browse {composer:field_output}
    </span>
{if:else}
....
```

[image]

To check if there is something wrong with my statement, I changed "file" to "text". The conditional then worked and wrapped all text inputs in the `<span>` mark-up. So the conditional statement itself appears to work correctly - just not for field_type "file" though.

If there some special statement/conditional that I'm missing to be able to control the output of field_type = "file"?

**Version Info:**

ExpressionEngine: 2.10.1
Freeform Pro: 4.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Composer **at all**...

This would be comment if it weren't going to be so long.

OK, so let's debug. I'm not sure if this is a production template. If so, holy crap-a-rolla, make a duplicate of the template in question, and set it to only-view-able by Super Admins. Work with that template and leave production alone. If this template is totally in dev-mode, ignore most of this paragraph. The next important part is to set PHP parsing on `output` for this template.

Next, let's see what we're getting from `{composer:field_type}`.

```
{composer:fields}
    {if composer:field_output}
        <?php
        var_dump('{composer:field_type}');
        ?>
    {/if}
{/composer:fields}
```

What is the outcome of that `var_dump()` for the fields that you expect to be `{composer:field_type}` as `"file"` ?

I've run into many issues where the EE parsing engine ends up outputting a weird value for something like a string like `file` ... it sometimes ends up as a a string with (made up example):

```
string(15) "file"
```

Something seem wrong there `:P` ? Are there 15 characters in the string `file`?

Report back and I'll apply some more sleuthing if I can help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The thing is - the file type attributes are standard HTML elements (like text, email, password, submit). The element IDs & Names contain the strings but the "type" doesn't. I'll still give your suggestion a go shortly. Thanks

Comment: ... but template tags and EE parsing have everything to do with it's output ... I'd assume they are broken, if anything. My answer/comment was meant to address a possible issue in the parsing engine. Literally the output of the engine to the rendered front-end page is your issue.

Comment: To explain a little further.. you have a conditional that makes programmatic sense, but isn't resolving as such. So there is an issue to overcome; and the EE templating engine has always needed review.

Comment: Thanks for the further comms - you were 100% correct. After implementing the snippet, the output of the file type for "file" is actually "file_upload": http://screencast.com/t/sGx1w1sszHqL